# OS X and rabbitMQ: ERROR: epmd error for host xxx: address (cannot connect to host/port)

Tags: rabbitmq, osx-mavericks

I just made to the latest OS X maverick update and I got suprised to see that rabbitMQ is no longueur working.
I get the following error:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Julio:~ julio$ rabbitmq-server
ERROR: epmd error for host MacBook-Pro-de-Julio: address (cannot connect to host/port)
```

I use the standalone version of `rabbitMQ`. I try to re-install it without any success. When I run `hostname` command I have the following result:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Julio:~ julio$ hostname
MacBook-Pro-de-Julio.local
```

Do you know how to fix this issue?

**EDIT 1:**

By turning off the Wifi, I can run with success rabbitMQ. If I turn it on, I can't launch rabbitMQ.

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks to @old_sound answer, I fixed the issue by editing my `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: `sudo` should helps you, in addition, make sure you followed the [OS X installation manual](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-standalone-mac.html) (I'm pretty sure you did, but just in case someone forget to that).

Comment: try adding your hostname to your /etc/hosts Sometimes Erlang distribution will get confused when your network changes. Otherwise try restarting epmd using `epmd -kill` or similar commands

Comment: old_sound: Thank you it works now after editing the `/etc/hosts`

Comment: @old_sound : What ip address should one give for this hostname?

Answer (score 58):

ERROR: epmd error for host HostName: timeout (timed out)

```
sudo mcedit /etc/hosts
```

add line

```
127.0.0.1 HostName
```

resolve my problems (ubuntu)

Find the host name by running command `echo $HOSTNAME`

Comment: Is HostName a literal or something else? Should my /etc/hosts file contain that exact line or something similar to it?

Comment: I followed this answer and it indeed solved the issue for me. The `HostName` is the hostname of your machine. Also, `+` is not literal - just add that line to `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Also solved my issue on OSX. Had to include `127.0.0.1  HostName.localdomain`

Comment: This `127.0.0.1 HostName` (witouth + of course) solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamMichalik : It does not solve the issue on my machine. In fact when I turn off the wi-fi and start the server it works fine. I was wondering what does it have to do with the network

Comment: In my case the error said "ERROR: epmd error for host Haris-MacBook-Pro: timeout (timed out)". I then added the line "127.0.0.1       Haris-MacBook-Pro" to my /etc/hosts on OSX.

Answer (score 3):

This exception never happened to me but appeared today. This worked for me:

- Disconnected from vpn
- Started rabbitmq (started successfully now)
- Reconnected to VPN

Disconnected from vpn Started rabbitmq successfully Reconnected to vpn

And I was able to connect to rabbitmq successfully, so the host resolved successfully even after reconnecting to vpn.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error message on linux VM (centos) after a clean install of Erlang and RabbitMQ.
I noticed epmd was trying to use the hostname instead of localhost.

My solution was to add the **4369** port to the firewall exceptions.

**Additional details in case it helps others...**

After calling "rabbitmqctl start_app" it would wait about 2 minutes, then fail with this error in the log file: "epmd error for {hostname}".

I falsely assumed that rabbitmq would be using localhost or 127.0.0.1 by default, but in my case it was using the hostname, which would resolve to the public static IP address.

I was able to work around this by exposing port **4369** through my firewall.

I assume that I could have changed my config to use localhost and avoid the firewall hole, but I wanted to expose it through the firewall eventually anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I brew installed rabbitmq, and had this problem several weeks later after installing.

You may have a look at

```
/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
```

make sure the value of hostname equals the value of NODENAME

You can set the value of hostname by

```
sudo scutil --set HostName xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

My workstation had this problem for no apparent reason. Right after the installation of rabbitmq I did the tutorials and everything worked fine. Then the workstation crashed and after the reboot I got the above error.

I found that my `/etc/hosts` file pointed the local HostName to `127.0.0.2` (no idea why, it's a company box) and after changing it to `127.0.0.1` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Open your host file `/etc/hosts` and check if this is present `127.0.0.1 localhost` if not add it. sometimes it just being commented. If so, uncomment it.